# Seeking an expression for phase shifts for scattering by a complex potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

Scattering from a complex potential, $V(r)=V_R(r)+iV_I(r)$, can take into account the absorption of a beam of particles. In this case, the phase shifts, $\delta_\ell(k)$, are complex. It is expected that the complex nature of $\delta_\ell(k)$ is a direct consequence of the complex nature of the potential $V(r)$.

Here is the question. Is there a mathematical relation, in the theory of partial wave analysis extended to complex central potentials, that relates the imaginary part of the phase shifts, $\delta_\ell(k)$, with the imaginary part of the complex potential, $V(r)$? Even if such an expression is not there, is there a way to see that the vanishing of $V_I(r)$ makes the imaginary part of the phase shift vanish? I am also okay with one-dimensional scattering theory. Feel free to use standard textbook expressions.